# Sudo - target user environment

Tags: sudo, environment-variables

Is there a way (without jumping through too many hoops) to run `sudo -u`*`user command`* in such a way that *`user`*'s environment is entirely preserved?

Basically, what I need is to ensure that specific environment variables are set for all users allowed to run sudo to impersonate certain IDs - mostly things like `PATH`, `JAVA_HOME`, and database-related (Oracle and Postgres) variables.

In other words - when I, as the user `wobble`, run `sudo -u wibble echo $PATH` I'd like to see `wibble`'s path displayed instead of `wobble`'s.

Comment: Do you also want sudo to remove all of `wobble`'s environment?

Comment: Not necessarily, but I need the PATH and other environment variables set for wibble to be available to everyone who runs commands *as* wibble

Comment: Does `wibble` set environment variables in something like `.bashrc`, `.kshrc`. or `.cshrc`?  Or are they set in `.profile` or `.login` or `.bash_profile` or files that they source? The latter may require giving `sudo` the `-i` option, which may result in unwanted output if `.profile` et al are chatty.

Comment: wibble sets env variables in .bashrc, and for some reason in RHEL6 sudo -i does not seem to work unless in the form "sudo -i -u wibble bash -c"

Comment: sudo -u webm echo $PATH  
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/i17454_adm/bin  
sudo -i -u webm bash -c 'echo $PATH'  
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/i17454_adm/bin:/opt/webm/admin/scripts:/home/webm/bin

Comment: Sorry - two-space linebreaks do not seem to work either. Is it me?

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly do the following for all users, or a given user wobble,
however it applies to all commands `sudo -u anyuser`. Edit the `/etc/sudoers` file and add a line like

```
Defaults env_keep+="PATH JAVA_HOME"
```

for all users, or

```
Defaults:wobble env_keep+="PATH JAVA_HOME"
```

for just wobble, with all the variables you want to keep. Actually, `PATH` is usually a special case, and is reset so you may need to cancel that with an entry like

```
Defaults:wobble  !secure_path, env_keep+="PATH JAVA_HOME"
```

Obviously, these features are there for good reason, so beware.

There is also the ability to preserve the environment with `sudo -E` which can be allowed by a sudoers entry like:

```
wobble ALL = (wibble) SETENV: ALL
```

but this will still reset the special case PATH, though you can run commands like

```
sudo -E PATH=$PATH -u wibble ...
```

Comment: I think OP wants the opposite of this - he wants commands run as `wibble` to have `wibble`'s environment.

Comment: Oops, did I confuse a wibble with a wobble? As the original user's PATH is normally lost, I assumed that was what they wanted to preserve, since as you say `-i` is easy to add for the reverse case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sudo -i` to go through the full login processes for a user, so `sudo -i -u wibble command` will login as wibble, setup all its environment vars and run command as that user.

However `sudo -i -u wibble echo $HOME` will still print out your home path. This is because your prompt is expanding the $HOME var before sudo even starts and there is nothing sudo can do about this. So if you need to pass a environment variable in through the command line it must be escaped properly, here are some examples:

```
sudo echo $HOME
> /home/user
sudo -i echo '$HOME'
> /root
sudo echo '$HOME'
> $HOME
sudo bash -c 'echo $HOME'
> /root
sudo -i bash -c 'echo $HOME'
> /root
```

To all of these you can add `-u wibble` (before the command) to run them as wibble instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
sudo su - USER
```

This will launch a shell with only the *USERs* environment variables (`SUDO_USER` etc. is removed as well):

```
   -, -l, --login
          Start the shell as a login shell with an environment similar to a real login
```